# How to get the time at which a comment was posted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying use the facebook api to get the last posts from the newsfeed of a user along with the comments attached to it. It's easy to get information about those comments such as the text, the actor id, etc... from a query to the STREAM table,

var query   = FB.Data.query('SELECT post_id, actor_id, app_data, message, attribution, created_time, comments FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid={0} AND type="newsfeed") LIMIT 20', response.id);

but it doesn't seem to include the timestamp at which those comments were posted (so I can get the timestamp for the post itself with 'created_time', but not for the comments attached to it).
Does anybody know a way to do this?
Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to be included in the 'comments' array returned by the query

Comment: actor_id
 "647177129"
 
I'm just getting the following fields:                        actor_name
actor_pic
actor_profile
message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample response from a query to the table `stream`

[image]

You could fetch that with something like

```
var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT post_id, actor_id, app_data, message, attribution, created_time, comments FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid={0} AND type="newsfeed") LIMIT 20', response.id);
query.wait(function(rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if (rows[i].stream_post.comments.count > 0) {
            var comments_list = rows[i].stream_post.comments.comment_list;
            for (var j = 0; j < comments_list.length; j++) {
                var comment = comments_list[j];
                alert(comment.time);//timestamp
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: Have not debugged the JavaScript. typos may be present.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot Naveen, just really strange that firebug did not show that field in the array I console.logged

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
$resultObject->comments->comment_list[0]->time
```

there is the unix timestamp from the comment created time.